# array_filter return value array for key in MultiDimensional array

Tags: multidimensional-array, key, array-filter

How to return value for key groupC using array_filter in this example

> $array = array('groupA'=>array(8,10,6,1,9),
>   'groupB'=>array(5,6,9,3,2), 'groupC'=>array(1,6,4,5));

```
function check($var)
{   
   $str = 4;    
   if($str%2 == 0){
      //return 'groupC'=>array(1,6,4,5);
   }    
}

array_filter($array, 'check');
```

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you want to return array groupC from your callback function "check".http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

from the code above i am assuming the length of groupC array would always be 4.
if you get count of that array is 4 then return the array. this is shown in the code below.
you can use the count function of PHP ([PHP Count function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php))

```
  function check($var)
    {   
       if(count($var)=='4')
       {
         return $var;
       }    
    }
print_r(array_filter($array, 'check'));
```

print_r in the end to check your result.

Also please keep in mind that this will return all elements of array that contain sub arrays of length 4.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but is it Possible have the same count with groupB and groupA

Comment: basically your function "check" determines what to return. so based on your input you can change the function to your liking to find a unique identifier that will return what you require by iterating through the array. in this case it was length of sub array which determines what is to be returned.